# inline server tag not working for asp.net control

Tags: asp.net, localization, inline-code, server-tags

Following is not working

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText='<%=class.getText("Address")%>' SortExpression="FirstName">blah blah</asp:TemplateField>
```

I cannot use "#" as this is not databind element i.e HeaderText='<%#class.getText("Address")%>'

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to set the HeaderText property in the backed, in PageInit most likely.  ASP.NET server controls cannot have ASP original server tags in it, only markup can.

Comment: After research i found that i can like this. headertext='<%$Resources:resource,id%>' but it isnt working for me.